# Custom TabBar in universal iOS App

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I am looking to recreate the raised tab bar as seen in many apps but am looking to do this in a universal app where the raised position would need to change.

At the moment I am not having much luck creating this so have come here for enlightenment, failing this I may just create a custom tab bar background.

If this is the case, would this work in the app delegate to differentiate the two devices?

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

UITarBar *tabBar = [UITabBar appearance];
[tabBar setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"iPadtabBar.png"]];

}
else {

UITarBar *tabBar = [UITabBar appearance];
[tabBar setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhonetabBar.png"]];

}
```

You may be thinking, why doesn't he just test it.. well that would be easier and if I could I would rather than ask first but I don't get my Mac back until the start of next week!

Comment: Would this work?  A device or simulator would know better then anyone here.  But more importantly, doing this in the app delegate is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: @nhgrif there are times where I could see the tab bar being set up in the app delegate. It may not be the generally accepted way compared to doing it in storyboard or in the main view controller, but I have seen it done before

Comment: Do it in a `UITabBar` or `UITabBarController` subclass...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to subclass UITabBarController and customize that center tab button. There is a nicely done example here: https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/RaisedCenterTabBar/Classes

Header file:
    @interface CustomTabBarViewController : UITabBarController{
    }

```
// Create a view controller and setup it's tab bar item with a title and image
-(UIViewController*) viewControllerWithTabTitle:(NSString*)title image:(UIImage*)image;

// Create a custom UIButton and add it to the center of our tab bar
-(void) addCenterButtonWithImage:(UIImage*)buttonImage highlightImage:(UIImage*)highlightImage;

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
@implementation CustomTabBarViewController

// Create a view controller and setup it's tab bar item with a title and image
-(UIViewController*) viewControllerWithTabTitle:(NSString*) title image:(UIImage*)image
{
    UIViewController* viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:title image:image tag:0];
    return viewController;
}

// Create a custom UIButton and add it to the center of our tab bar
-(void) addCenterButtonWithImage:(UIImage*)buttonImage highlightImage:(UIImage*)highlightImage
{
    UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:highlightImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    CGFloat heightDifference = buttonImage.size.height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height;
    if (heightDifference < 0)
        button.center = self.tabBar.center;
    else
    {
        CGPoint center = self.tabBar.center;
        center.y = center.y - heightDifference/2.0;
        button.center = center;
    }

    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: This answer should, at a minimum, include sample code snippet highlights from the provided link.  The basics of subclassing a UITabBarController are unlikely to change too drastically any time soon... however links to websites (especially unofficial documentation websites) have a tendency to die, rendering the answer completely useless.

Comment: I'm doing all of this through storyboards and many CollectionViewControllers, would I need to put a button into the storyboard over the tabbar? Also how do I set what image is displayed? and do I have to import said subclass into each viewcontroller? sorry complete newbie!